# Async void on subscribed Prism methods

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, prism

I understand you should try not to do `async void` with the exception of event handlers. Does that exception of event handlers include Prism events? Is my example below ok to do?

Module A's View has a `DataGrid` and when the user clicks a record it publishes the `SelectionChangedEvent`, the event is subscribed in Module B and might take a while to complete.

```
    public class ModuleA 
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Company> carCollectionOC = new ObservableCollection<Company>();        

        private void CarCollection_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Company company = (Company)(sender as ICollectionView).CurrentItem;
            this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<SelectionChangedEvent>().Publish(company.Brand);
        }  
    }
```

Module B subscribes and does `async void`.

```
public class ModuleB 
{
        private ObservableCollection<Vehicle> vehicleOC = new ObservableCollection<Vehicle>();
        private VehicleService vehicleService;

        public ModuleB(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            this.vehicleService = new VehicleService();                    
            this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<SelectionChangedEvent>()
                          .Subscribe(this.SubscribedMethod,
                          ThreadOption.UIThread,
                          false);
        }

        private async void SubscribedMethod (string brand)
        {
            this.vehicleOC = await this.GetData(brand);
        }

        private List<Vehicle> GetVehicles(string carBrand)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("finishing GetVehicles");
            return this.vehicleService.GetVehicleList(carBrand);
        }

        private async Task<ObservableCollection<Vehicle>> GetData(string carBrand)
        {
            vehicleListFromService = await Task.Run(() => this.GetVehicles(carBrand));
            
            this.vehicleOC.Clear();
            foreach (var vehicle in vehicleListFromService)
                this.vehicleOC.Add(vehicle);

            return this.vehicleOC;

        }        
}
```

Comment: The method used in `Subscribe` is not a subscribed method, it's a subscriber method. What is being subscribed is an event. Thus, event aggregator.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, even stephen clearly (an authority on this subject as far as i am concerned) says:

> To summarize this first guideline, you should prefer async Task to
> async void. Async Task methods enable easier error-handling,
> composability and testability. The exception to this guideline is
> asynchronous event handlers, which must return void. This exception
> includes methods that are logically event handlers even if they’re not
> literally event handlers (for example, ICommand.Execute
> implementations).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

Personally, I always wrap the contents of an `async void` method in a `try-catch` and deal with the exception, regardless of the method's contents. I've written a simple helper class to aid with that.

Comment: While it's true that one should always prefer `async Task` over `async void`, I'd say that giving `PubSubEvent.Subscribe` an overload that accepts a true `async Task` handler would make a lot more sense than a band-aid wrapper. This is not a native .Net event, we can modify the code (or rather use one's own variant of `PubSubEvent` that creates a subscription to the `async Task`)...

Answer (score 0):

> Does that exception of event handlers include Prism events?

Yes. The subscriber has to be `Action`, that means `void MyHandler()` (or `async void MyHandler()`).